# How to know if a coordinate is inside city or state boundaries

Tags: web-services, google-maps, location, polygon, saas

Let's say I have a list of objects with coordinates (latitude longitude) in the US.

Now, I want to get the list of objects that are 'within' the boundaries of Los Angeles.
And after that, I want the list of objects that are 'within' the boundaries of the state of California.

How would I go about completing that task (using an external service for example)? 
Is there a SaaS service for City/State polygonal data?

---

I'm aware that there is a longer path of doing so, like:

1. Iterate the list of objects,using reverse-geocoding (using [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) for example).
2. Save the returned State and City for all the objects.
3. Search for object that contain Los Angeles or California in the relevant 'fields'.

I simply want to see more approaches to the problem.

Thanks!